# Create only one Scanner object java

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to create one Scanner object to use in multiple places.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
private static Scanner keyboard;
public void doesSomething(String stringName){
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    ...
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    ...
}
```

I previously tried using the new keyword in the creation of that instance variable but that didn't work because of some of the specifics of my code, but that's not my question. My question is simply- are these two Scanner objects or is this one object?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you run `doesSomething` you will create a new `Scanner`, forget about the old one stored in `keyboard` if there is one (it will late be garbage collected), and proceed. `main` will also create a new `Scanner` and put it in `keyboard`.

You will not be closing the old `Scanner`, which is a resource leak (i.e. it's bad so you don't want to create a zillion `Scanner`s and throw them away improperly).

Answer (score 1):

Each time you invoke `new ...` you are creating separate object. So if you invoke `main` once and lets say it will invoke `doesSomething` you will end up with two Scanner objects.

So remove `keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);` from `doesSomething` method since you don't really need it as this method already have access to `keyboard` field which will be initialized in `main` method.

You could also change `keyboard` from being field and lat it be local variable in `main` method. After that change let `doesSomething` method accept `Scanner` as argument

```
public void doesSomething(String stringName, Scanner keyboard){
    ...
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ...
    instance.doesSomething("something", sc);
    ...
}
```

and pass scanner you created in `main` method